# Is there a UI component that lets me select a path in oracle adf?

Tags: java, user-interface, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I was searching for a UI component that let me browse through my file system to choose a path in a page in oracle ADF to generate a file in this specific location. I couldn't find anything other then inputFile which uploads a file but I need to save a file.

Any suggestions? I searched a lot couldn't find any relevant info.

Thanks

Comment: Hey Alain, don't forget to accept answers that helped : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

To download a file you have to use the af:fileDownloadActionListener component like this :

```
<af:commandButton text="Say Hello">
          <af:fileDownloadActionListener filename="hello_txt"
                                    contentType="text/plain; charset=utf-8"
                                    method="#{bean.sayHello}"/>
</af:commandButton>
```

See : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16162_01/apirefs.1112/e17491/tagdoc/af_fileDownloadActionListener.html